# Dynamically building accessors in ruby on object initialization

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, attr-accessor

I created a ruby wrapper around a json API that converts json formatted responses into ruby object. A typical resource looks like that :

```
module Learning360
  class User
    attr_accessor(
      :_id,
      :mail,
      :firstName,
      :lastName,
      :assignedPrograms,
      :paths,
      :certifications,
      :championAchievements,
      :comments,
      :completedPrograms,
      :groups,
      :imageUrl,
      :labels,
      :lastLoginAt,
      :championStatus,
      :learnerAchievements,
      :managers,
      :messages,
      :publications,
      :reactions,
      :skills,
      :subordinates,
      :toDeactivateAt,
      :totalTimeSpentInMinutes,
      :custom
    )

    def initialize(options = {})
      options.map { |(k, v)| send("#{k}=", v) }
    end
  end
end
```

When I receive the json payload, I pass it to the initializer as a hash of options and I then assign each one of the key its value as an instance variable.
This works well as long as I maintain an updated list of `attr_accessor`. However if the API decides to change the naming of its keys or add a new key this will throw a

```
undefined method `unexpected_key_from_api=' for #<Learning360::User>
```

How can I avoid that problem and make my wrapper more robust. I would like my wrapper object to just take any key from the response and automatically build the corresponding accessor if it doesnt exist.

Comment: You could look at how [`OpenStruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) works or possibly just use `OpenStruct` (with some sort of whitelisting to avoid the usual caveats).

Comment: I would argue you cannot really make your code more robust against changes from the upstream API. Because even if your wrapper would be able to handle it then the next method downstream would fail when expected attributes are not available anymore. Therefore my only advice is: When an API returns an unexpected response format, log the full response and raise loud.

Comment: I can agree with @spickermann I recently implemented a wrapper for a living API. (The company is continually changing spec) While I did not "raise loud" I implemented logging of disposed attributed (unmapped attributes) and also threw a `warn` in for good measure. This has been working well to this point.

Comment: Also since this appears to be a consumer API is accessor needed or just reader? If just reader you could go with 1 of 2 options `define_method` or `method_missing` and just store the reponse as as `Hash` Example: `def initialize(options={}); @options = options; options.keys.each {|k| define_method(k) { @options[k] }}; end` or `def method_missing(attr_name,*args,&block); return super unless @options.key?(attr_name); @options[attr_name]; end` but this offers a continually changing interface which I am not a fan of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create attributes with `attr_accessor` inside the `initialize` method. You only need to reach to it like below:

```rb
module Learning360
  class User
    def initialize(options = {})
      options.each do |(k, v)|
        self.class.attr_accessor(k)
        send("#{k}=", v)
      end
    end
  end
end

user = Learning360::User.new({ name: "Matz" })
puts user.name  # Matz
```

It is also possible to use class name diectly just like `User.attr_accessor(k)`.